# Photoshop: How to match scale of the same object in two images with different dimensions?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, scale

**How to match scale of the exact same object that appears in 2 images with different dimensions?**

Let me explain my use case:
[image]

- There once was a hi-res photo of a Cat (original)
- Someone cropped it (image A)
- Another person cropped another part of it & downscaled the photo (image B)

I don't have the original photo anymore, only image A & B.

If image B wasn't downscaled, it would be easy to pixel match & combine them. But that's not the case here.

Other than manually using the Transform tool to try & approximate the scale, is there a way to stitch the images in a more 'pixel perfect' way? Given that I know its the exact same object in two photos, just that the dimensions & scale are different.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this automatically by using the Photomerge feature in Photoshop. The images do not have to be the same size for this to work.

1. File -> Automate -> Photomerge
2. Choose Auto for the Layout
3. Browse for your images that you would like to merge
4. Press OK. Photoshop will create a new document with the merged images.